# SQLite command gives different output on Python than DB Browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I entered the code in the triple quotation marks below into the DB Browser, SQL Executor, and it output the values which I desired. When I used the python code, which is what the below is, all the values within the database table are output. What have I done wrong? In order to use SQLites Y-m-d format I've already had to change every date input and output.

```sql
SQL = ("""SELECT *
       FROM Vat
       WHERE %s >= DateTimeSet""")%(self.Date)
       Cursor = self.Connection.cursor()
       for row in Cursor.execute(SQL):
          print(row)
```

Comment: Don't use the `str % tuple` syntax for binding your SQL statements. In your case, I believe you're missing quotation marks around `%s`. Refer to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) for examples.

Comment: `2019-02-24` is the integer 1993... So yes, use parameters for binding values to things in a query instead of string substitution.